# App widget does not update textview even onUpdate method works

Tags: android, android-widget

My problem is I have an app widget which needs to be updated in every 32 mins. However, it's not updating the textview. I placed Log entry to my onUpdate method to see is it working on Logcat, and i confirmed method is working properly but just it's not changing the value of textview. Here is my code;
AppWidgetProvider:

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ComponentName thisWidget=new ComponentName(context, 
            IzUlasimProvider.class);
    int[] allWidgetIds=appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);

    for(int id:allWidgetIds){
        String now=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(new Date());

        RemoteViews views=new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvWidget,now);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(id, views);
        now=null;
    }
    Log.w("Update","Update Finished");
}
```

My config file:

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:initialLayout="@layout/widget" 
android:minHeight="110dp" 
android:updatePeriodMillis="1920000" 
android:minWidth="250dp" android:configure="com.izulasim.widget.IzWidgetConfig">
```

AndroidManifest part for the widget:

```
<receiver android:name="com.izulasim.widget.IzWidgetProvider">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_config" />
    </receiver>
    <activity
        android:name="com.izulasim.widget.IzWidgetConfig"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <provider android:name=".IzUlasimProvider" 
        android:authorities="com.izulasim.provider.IzUlasim" />
```

Comment: Why are you using *allWidgetIds* and not *appWidgetIds* ?